# Backtracking asynchronous JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to **backtrack** the code below. Until now, I understand that the `getResults()` function uses **asynchronous JavaScript** but I am still unable to understand is the value of variable `res` and who calls the function  `success: function(res)` . Please guide. Thanks

```
function getResults(u) {                                    // function called from index page
// alert("Inside get results");                             // show that we are in
    $.ajax({                                                // asynchrounous javascript starts to run 
        dataType: "jsonp",                                  // 
        url: u,
        success: function(res) {                            // 
              $("#status").hide();                          //
              if (res.data.length) {                        //
                nexturl = res.paging.next;                  //
                  $.each(res.data, function(i,item){        //
                    if (item.id != lastid) {                //
                        lastid = item.id;                   //
                        var html ="<div class=\"post\">";   //
                        html += "<div class=\"message\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id="+item.from.id+"\">"+item.from.name+"</a> ";
                        if (item.message) {                 //
                            html += item.message+"<\/div>"; //
                        } else {                            //
                            html += "<\/div>";              //
                        }
                        if (item.picture) {                 //
                            html += "<div class=\"image\"><img src=\""+item.picture+"\"></div>";    //
                        } else {                            //
                            html += "<div class=\"image\"><\/div>";                                 //
                        };
                        if (item.link) {                    //
                            html += "<div class=\"link\"><a href=\""+item.link+"\">"+item.name+"</a></div>";    //

                            if (item.caption) {             //
                                    html += "<div class=\"caption\">"+item.caption+"</div>";                    //
                            };
                            if (item.description) {         //
                                    html += "<div class=\"description\">"+item.description+"</div>";            //
                            };  

                        };

                        html += "<div class=\"meta\">";                                                         //

                        if (item.icon) {                                                                        //
                            html += "<span class=\"icon\"><img src=\""+item.icon+"\"></span> ";                 //
                        };
                        var t = item.created_time;                                                              //
                        var time = t.substring(0,19)+"\+00:00";                                                 //
                        html += "<span class=\"time\">"+$.cuteTime({},time)+"<\/span> ";                        //
                        html += " <\/div>";                                                                     //

                        html +="</div>";                                                                        //
                        $("#data").append(html) ;                                                               //
                    }
                  });
                    $("#more").appendTo("#data");                                                               //
                    $("#more").show();                                                                          //
                    $("#status").appendTo("#data");                                                             //


            } else {                                                                                            //
                $("#data").append("<h3 class=\"none\">No entries found. Please try another search.</h3>");      //
            }; 
        } 

    });
}
```

Comment: dont understand your question. This is a standard jquery ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Use `console.log` to determine value of variable

Comment: Success is called when the ajax call receives a 200 (OK) result, and res is the data that was sent back.

Comment: `res` is what's returned from the server

Comment: Are you sure you want jsonp?  Side note: this code looks like a mess. :)  Use single quotes on your html += '' so there's not so much  \ escaping.  Also split this html handling off into separate functions that returns an html string, and then to attach the string to the dom.

Answer (score 1):

success is called automatically if the ajax call ends, and ends succesfully (code 200).
res is the string returned by server to your call. in this case, is in jsonp format. in this case, the results.

As you see, res is used as an object, just like any other json response.

Answer (score 0):

Success is automatically called when the ajax request successfully returns. The function is passed back 3 arguments:

> success: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard JQuery AJAX call. The success function is called once the ajax call returns successfully. `res` is the result of the ajax call.

Check the JQuery docs for more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/